# Nameservers not resolving

Tags: nameservers

I am trying to get a website to resolve correctly but am running into some issues. The website is hosted on a public cloud instance through OVH with CentOS7 and CWP for the control panel. You can view the issues here:

https://intodns.com/klickado.com

I have setup the 2 nameservers on Enom, added A records for nsk1 and nsk2 on the ambientwave.com domain and pointed the klickado.com domain to the correct nameservers but something isnt resolving correctly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find the issue. It seems your issue has been solved.